# Capturing events on embedded charts within Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-charts

I am trying to embedded column chart in Google sheets and would like to capture events like which column was clicked, then use the info to highlight certain cells. Is that even possible in embedded Google charts within Google spreadsheets?

So far, I have found that:

1. I can get Class EmbeddedChart's object and get/modify its attributes like title.
2. I can work with google.visualization apis (which allows event capture), but do not know how to embed them to google sheets.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Short answer. No. What do yo mean by "I can work with google.visualization apis..."?

Comment: @Rubén, I mean as per the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events), google chart have event listeners using google.visualization.events.addListener, but this so far seems like client side javascript to add charts. I would try to explore if I can somehow use these to embedd charts in google sheets, but not sure if that would work.

Comment: AFAIK event listener can't be used with embedded in a spreadsheets charts, only on charts embedded in a web page. The available triggers that can be used on Google Sheets are described on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable